# Search for ISBN's in a column and copy those to a new cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

I have tried many of the suggestions within SU and Reddit for a solution to my problem, I have a large (7000 row) sheet with book(s) data. Each row is a specific book. Within column (D) it has a description of the book but sometimes (40%) it also includes the ISBN for that book. The ISBN contains numbers (but sometimes an x) in various formats (ISBN-10, ISBN-13) They have been manually entered, so sometimes they include a space or a dash -. I need to search for the number string, then copy what is found into an adjacent cell (AV). Even if it could only catch the 10 or 13 digit ISBN's (without spaces or dash) it would solve a huge headache. I am using Planmaker on Linux, but could transfer to Excel or Libreoffice Calc if needed. Thanks.

Sample added:
[enter link description here](https://transfernow.net/69e592c8myjz)

'''5393 Arboriculture and Trees > History and Folklore  The Living Wisdom of Trees  Detailed tree-by-tree coverage of more than 55 trees; describing their natural history, folklore, symbolism, healing powers.

224pp, colour photos (many full-page, and the majority by Edward PARKER). Hardback; in dust-jacket.

ISBN 1844831647 0           no  no          1.3     no  no      no          no      Duncan Baird    no  0       Out of print    0           1844831647|book|trees|legend|history|hageneder  0               0       0       0       0   1844831647  yes     55  2005    Fred Hageneder
5394    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Identification   Trees - A Field Guide to the Trees of Britain and N. Europe Out of Print
OUP. 2005. 431pp, colour photos, drawings, distribution maps. Photographic identification guide based on leaf shape and configuration, with thorough but non-technical descriptions related to the photos.

ISBN 019851574X 0           no  no          0       no  no      no          no      Oxford University Press no  0       Out of print    0           019851574X|trees|identification|british|photographic|guide|botany|arboriculture 0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2005    J. White & S.M. Walters 
5395    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Identification   Pocket Nature: Trees    Compact pocket sized guide to over 300 species. 224pp, illustrated in colour throughout.

ISBN 13: 9780751338720  ISBN 10: 0751338729 0           yes no          0.3     no  no      no      3339    no      Dorling Kindersley  no  0           0           Coombes|Pocket|Nature|Guide|Trees|9780751338720|0751338729  0               0       0       0       0   ISBN 13: 9780751338720  ISBN 10: 0751338729 yes     55  2004    Alan Coombes
5396    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Identification   Easy Tree Guide Making equal use of colour photos and paintings by Gill Tomblin and Ann Winterbotham, with illustrated  keys and an easy-to-understand text, this is a very useful identification guide.
288pp, colour photos and illustrations throughout.  0           no  no          0       no  no      no          no      Aurum Press no  0       Out of print    0           Rushforth|Easy|Tree|Guide   0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2006    K Rushforth 
5397    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Families and Genera  Witch Hazels    227pp. 144 col. photos. Comprehensive guide to the history, botany and cultivation of the species of the genus Hamamelis. The first monograph on these fascinating winter-flowering shrubs. A Royal Horticultural Society Plant Collector Guide. Hardback; with dust-jacket.

ISBN 13:  9780881926781  ISBN 10: 0881926787    0           yes no          1       no  no      no          no      Timber P.   no  0       Out of print    0           0881926787|9780881926781|book|hazel|witch|hamamelis|botany|gardening|landscape  0               0       0       0       0   ISBN 13:  9780881926781  ISBN 10: 0881926787    no      55  2005    Chris Lane. 
5398    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Families and Genera  Pinaceae    Drawings and descriptions of the genera Abies, Cedrus, Pseudolarix, Keteleeria, Nothotsuga, Tsuga, Cathaya, Pseudotsuga, Larix and Picea. The work supplements Farjon's earlier wotk on the genus Pinus and reflects his desire to encourage the protection of the remaining coniferous species as interesting remnants of a plant world from the distant past. The arrangement of the work is taxonomical. A definitive work.

330pp. Tall hardback. Superb line drawings throughout. 
ISBN-10: 3874292983 
ISBN-13: 9783874292986  0           no  no          1.4     no  no      no          no      Koeltz Scientific Books no  0           0           Farjon|Pinaceae|book|3874292983|9783874292986|koeltz|   0               0       0       0       0   ISBN-10: 3874292983 
ISBN-13: 97838742929    yes     55  1990    A Farjon
5399    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Families and Genera  World Checklist and Bibliography of Fagales THIS ITEM IS CURRENTLY ON OFFER: WAS £40.00 NOW £30.00
RBG Kew. 1998. 407pp, a few line drawings. Second in a series of publications intended to document families and other plant groups of particular interest to the Royal Botanic Gardens Kew, and to contribute to international efforts to record the world's biota.Covers the familes Betulaceae, Corylaceae, Fagaceae and Ticodendraceae. Large limpback.  30          no  no          1.58    no              no          no          no  0           9998            Fagales|Govaerts|Frodin 0               0       0       0       0       no      55  1998    Govaerts and Frodin 
5400    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Families and Genera  The Black Poplar - Ecology, History and Conservation    180pp. 30 col. photos. 30 b&w illus. When seen silhouetted against a winter sky on a river bank, the black poplar easily earns a place among Britain's largest, most charismatic trees. It is also one of the rarest, and its future is causing great concern amongst conservationists.

This is the first book to tell the full story of the black poplar in Britain: its historic place in the lanscape, its cultural role in poetry and folklore, its uses as timber and in medicine, and the reasons for its decline. Fiona Cooper explores how an understanding of the black poplar's genetic make-up can help promote its conservation. She examines in particular the famous populations in the Vale of Aylesbury and in urban Manchester, the latter of which is under great threat.

Published in paperback only.

ISBN 1905119054 18.5            no  no          1   no              no          no      Windgather P.   no  0           9999            book|1905119054|poplar  0               0       0       0       0   1905119054  no      55  2006
5401    Arboriculture and Trees > Tree Families and Genera  World Checklist and Bibliographyof Sapotaceae   This book presents the first full list (54 genera and 1175 species) of the family to appear since the mid-nineteenth century.  The Sapotaceae (the argan, chicle or gutta-percha family) are prominent in most of the wetter tropics and subtropics and are of considerable direct and indirect economic importance as sources of fine timber, fruit and vegetable oil as well as latex. Many are also planted as amenity trees. The circumscription of the genera follows that currently used at Kew, which is based on 'The Genera of the Sapotaceae' (1991) by T.D. Pennington. The 39 illustrations of representative species are mostly drawn from the Kew Illustration Collection.

372pp. Large format paperback.
ISBN 1900347946

```
78.5            no  no          1.5     no  no      no          no      Kew Publishing  no  0       To order 5-7 days delivery  0           1900347946|book|sapotaceae|kew|checklist    0               0       0       0       0   1900347946  no      55  2001    Rafael Govaerts et al   #NULL!
```

5402    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   World Checklist & Bibliography of Conifers  The definitive reference for botanists, horticulturists, foresters and conservationists - this second edition has been fully revised, and provides the most authoritative listing of conifer names through to the year 2000, with extensive information on distribution, conservation status and a bibliography of the most relevant scientific literature. Paperback.

ISBN 1842460250

```
50.5            no  no          1.4     no  no      no          no      Kew Publishing  no  0       To order 5-7 days delivery  0           1842460250|book|conifers|checklist|kew|trees|coniferae  0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2001    Aljos Farjon
```

5403    Botanical Art > Techniques  The Watercolour A to Z of Trees and Foliage An illustrated directory of techniques for painting 24 trees. 128pp, colour illustrations. Materials and techniques, followed by step-by-step, illustrated instructions for painting some of our more popular trees. Hardback

ISBN  1903975735    0           no  no          1       no  no      no      1107    no      Search Press    no  0           0           1903975735|painting|trees|watercolour|art   0               0       0       0       0       yes Out of print, but we can locate new and or used copies if needed. Contact us for information    99  2004
5404    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   A Photographic Guide to Trees of New Zealand    Paperback guide to 108 species, ordered by family.

128pp, colour photos, distribution maps. 
Truly pocket-sized
ISBN 1877246573

```
10.5            yes no          0.3     no  no      no          no      New Holland no  0       To order 5-7 days delivery  0           Photograph|Trees|New Zealand|Metcalf|1877246573 
0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2002    Laurie Metcalf
```

5405    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   Native Trees for North American Landscapes  Timber Press. 2004. 552pp, colour photographs throughout. Handsome volume designed to give assistance in the selection of native American trees appropriate to individual landscape requirements. More than 650 species and 500 cultivars are discussed, describing flowers and fruit, native and adaptive range, and seasonal features such as striking bark in winter, or vivid fruit in autumn. Large hardback..

```
0           no  no          0       no  no      no          no          no  0       Out of print    0           Native|Trees|North|American|Landscapes|Steinberg|Wilson|Book    0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2004    Steinberg and Wilson
```

5406    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   Brazilian Trees.  3 volume set  An encyclopaedic guide to the identification and cultivation of Brazilian trees; each species is accorded 6 colour photographs depicting full tree, twig and flower, fruit, seed, bark and timber. Substantial descriptive accounts are also given, covering botany, ecology, distribution, wood, uses, seed harvesting and propagation. Large format hardbacks in pictorial boards.

3 volumes. 384pp. each volume. Many col. photos. 
volume 1 ISBN 8586714178
volume 2 ISBN 8586714151
volume 3 ISBN 8586714344    0           yes no          5.5     no  no      no      1222,1905,1906,2527 no      I.P.E.F.    no  0           0           8586714178|8586714151|book|trees|brazilian|brazilian trees|brazil|lorenzi|  0               0       0       0       0       yes     99  2000 (4th edition)  Harri Lorenzi
5407    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   Generic Tree Flora of Madagascar    A practical field manual for the identification of the 500 genera of native and naturalized Malagasy trees.  Identification keys emphasise vegetative and gross morphological features. All genera are provided with full descriptions, distribution information, key characteristics, up-to-date taxonomic references and over 3,000 Malagasy vernacular names, and almost all are illustrated.

490pp. Paperback.
ISBN 1900347822

```
36          no  no          1.25    no              no          no      Kew Publishing  no  0           9998            1900347822|book|trees|madagascar|malagasy   0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2001    George E. Schatz
```

5408    Arboriculture and Trees > History and Folklore  A Passion for Trees: The Legacy of John Evelyn  Published in the year that marks the tercentenary of John Evelyn's death, this fitting celebration of our trees centres on Evelyn and his major work, Sylva: A Discourse of Forest Trees (1664). We are treated to portraits of over 30 best-loved trees, with constant reference to Evelyn's text, and additional information and commentary is added by the author. Well-presented and a pleasure to read. Hardback.282pp, colour illustrations.
ISBN  9781903919477 25          no  no  IN STOCK        1   no              no          no      Eden Project Books  no  0           9999            9781903919477|John Evelyn|Campbell-Culver!Passion|trees 0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    Maggie Campbell-Culver
5409    Arboriculture and Trees > Arboriculture Wood and Tree Fungi: Biology, Damage, Protection, and Use.  Provides an up-to-date overview of the various fungi which cause damage to trees, lumber and timber, with special focus on identification, prevention, and remediation techniques. A section on the fundamentals of morphology, biology and caustaive factors is followed by a practical examination of virus and bacteria damage, wood discoloration, decay by wood rot fungi and methods of prevention and tree care. The final section focuses on the positive effects of wood-inhabiting microorganisms, covering past and classical themes such as myco-wood, mushroom cultivation and biological pulping as well as recent bio technological processes.

334pp. Hardback. Figs and photos in col. and b&w.
ISBN 3540321381     79          no  yes         1       no  no      no      890,874,868 no      Springer    no  99.99       To order 1-2 weeks  0           arboriculture, disease, pathology, timber, mycology, 3540321381 0               0       0       0       0       no      27  2006    Olaf Schmidt
5410    Arboriculture and Trees > History and Folklore  Horse Chestnut  48pp. Short survey of the history and folklore surrounding the beloved 'conker' tree. Paperback 5           yes no          0.25        no  no      no          no      Privately published no  0           9999                0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2005    Chris Howkins
5411    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   Mythic Woods: The World's Most Remarkable Forests   176pp. Striking col. photos. A lavishly illustrated exploration of the many and diverse forest habitats of the world, from Amazon to Andes, Madagascar to Bangladesh. The author, whose earlier work 'Cabbages and Kings' was so widely acclaimed, gives a fascinating insight into the history, ecology, legends and traditions of forest life. Hardback; in dust-jacket.

ISBN 0297843524 25          no  no          1.4     no  no      no          no      Weidenfeld  no  0       To order 5-7 days delivery  0               0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2004    Jonathan Roberts
5412    Arboriculture and Trees > History and Folklore  Welsh Woods and Forests: A History  247pp., b&w photos and reproductions of engravings. A revised and updated edition of the author's earlier work, taking the account forward to the establishment of the Welsh Assembly in 1999, and the publication of a separate forestry strategy for Wales. Hardback; with dust-jacket.

ISBN 1859028640
    0           no  no          1       no  no      no          no      Gomer Press no  0       OUT OF PRINT    0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2000    William Linnard 
5413    Botanical Art > General Artist's Kew    96pp. Colour paintings. Well produced book published in association with an exhibition of contemporary paintings inspired by Kew Gardens held at Kew in May and June 2006. 
Hardback.

ISBN 1842461435 16.5            no  no          1       no  no      no          no      Kew Publishing  no  0       Out of print, but we can often locate new and used copies as needed. Contact us for information 0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2006    J. Cloake and R. Strong (eds.)
5414    Ecology, Habitat Management and Landscape History > Conservation Guides and Technical Manuals   The Wetland Restoration Manual  Pages unnumbered, in chapters and sections, b&w photos, substantial. The Wildlife Trust's UK Water Policy Team has gathered together examples of best practice both from their own experience and from their partners elsewhere in the conservation world. The manual offers practical advice on wetland restoration, creation and management. Large, heavy, plastic ring-binder.

ISBN 0902484923 0           no  no          3.75        no  no      no          no      The Wildlife Trusts no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     99  2005    P. Eades et al. 
5415    Plant Monographs > Family, Genus and Species    The Genus Arisaema: A Monograph for Botanists and Nature Lovers 2nd ed. 474pp, colour photos. Revised and enlarged edition of this, the first monograph on the genus within the Arum family since Engler's classification in 1910, including descriptions, taxonomy, names and synonyms, critical examinations of the nomenclature, geographic distribution and habitat, together with notes on cultivation. Hardback.

ISBN 3906166376 0           no  no          1.5     no  no      no          no      Gantner Verlag  no  0       Out of print    0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2006    G. & L. Gusman
5416    Plant Science > General Seed to Seed: The Secret Life of Plants 311pp, drawings and diagrams by Polly Napper. In diary form, "Nicholas Harberd's narrative of the changing seasons has as its focus one tiny thale-cress plant in an East Anglian churchyard. He describes both what can be seen with the naked eye and the hidden molecular mechanisms that underlie the visible events in the plant's life". The author directs a research team at the John Innes Centre. Hardback. 
ISBN 0747570396 16.5            no  no          0.71    no              no          no      Bloomsbury  no  0           9999                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    N. Harberd
5418    Plant Monographs > Family, Genus and Species    Buddlejas   RHS Plant Collector Guide Series. 192pp, colour photo section. David Stuart was Curator of Longstock Park Gardens for 14 years, during which period it held the National Collection of Buddleias. The first comprehensive coverage of the genus (comprising around 100 species), with descriptions and information for gardeners. There are no indigenous buddlejas in Australia, regions of the former Soviet Union, or Europe. Hardback.

ISBN-10 0881926884  ISBN-13  9780881926880  0           yes no          1       no  no      no          no      Timber Press    no  0           0           0881926884|9780881926880|book|buddlejas|Stuart|RHS  0               0       0       0       0       yes Out of print    55  2006    Stuart, D.D.
5419    Fauna > Birds   How To Identify Birds   176pp, colour paintings, distribution maps. Helps beginner birdwatchers with their greatest challenge: distinguishing similar species from one another. Learn to recognise 33 common species, and then, by comparison, a further 92 species. Description and behavioural traits, fact-file and lookalikes are given for each, with large, clear illustrations showing the bird in a variety of plumages. Paperback .

ISBN 000719448X 9.5         no  no          0.38    no              no          no      HarperCollins   no  0           9999                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    Nicholas Hammond
5420    European Flora > Spain, Portugal, the Canary Islands & the Azores   Trees of Portugal   64pp. Colour paintings. An introductory illustrated account of some of the more frequently encountered Portuguese trees. Paperback. 5           no  no          0.25    no              no          no      Privately published no  0           9995                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  1998    Mary McMurtrie
5421    British Botany > Local Floras > Wales   The Flowering Plants and Ferns of Denbighshire  This plant list is the first to be published for Denbighshire VC50. It is for the field botanist and plant lover who visits this part of Wales. It answers the question "is this plant rare?" and invites contributions to update records. Includes Latin, Welsh and English names. Paperback.  7.5         no  no      87pp, 4 maps of the area.   0.25        no  no      no          no      Privately published no  0           9995                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    Jean A. Green
5422    Horticulture and Gardening > Practical Gardening    Tomatoes    128pp, colour photos. Presents a selection of tomato varieties, with a wide range of sizes, colours and flavours, and gives cultivation advice. Hardback.

ISBN-10 187358072X   ISBN-13  9781873580721 16.5            no  no          0.85        no  no      no          no      Whittet Books   no  0       To order 5-7 days delivery  0           Tomatoes|Marshall|book|187358072x|9781873580721 0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    Terry Marshall
5423    Fauna > Mammals The New Hedgehog Book   208pp, drawings. Originally published under the title Hedgehogs in 1983, this expanded and updated edition imparts down-to-earth information with the same dry sense of humour and is illustrated with an entirely new set of drawings and cartoons by Guy Troughton. Hardback.

ISBN 1873580711 9.5         no  no          0.71    no              no          no      Whittet Books   no  0           9998                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    Pat Morris
5424    British Botany > Local Floras > Scotland    Flowers of Iona 3rd ed 2006. 47pp, map, original watercolours by the author. The list of flowering plants is brought up to 335; also includes rushes, sedges, grasses and ferns. Typical habitats are described. Includes common, botanical and Gaelic names. Paperback.

ISBN 0953893839 0           no  no          0.2     no  no      no          no      New Iona Press. no  0       Out of print    0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2006    Jean M. Millar
5425    Horticulture and Gardening > Practical Gardening    The Royal Horticultural Society Pruning & Training  The latest RHS guide to pruning provides a concise if less comprehensive manual than the larger Brickell and Joyce publication from the same stable. This guide to pruning and training includes detailed instructions on all the key techniques for tackling roses, fruit trees & bushes, shrubs, hedges, ornamental trees, climbers and even perennials. Colour step-by-step drawings and clear photography 
There is also a Pruning Directory of more than 160 common plants for quick reference and is fully illustrated throughout. 
Hardback
192 pages
ISBN: 9781845337797

```
0           no  no      21.1 x 15.5 x 2.3 cm    0.7     no  no      no          no      Mitchell Beazley    no  0       Out of print    0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2013    Royal Horticultural Society
```

5426    Fungi > General Need to Know? Mushroom Hunting  OUT of PRINT and currently unavailable

How to safely identify edible wild mushrooms. 192pp, colour photos throughout. Organised by habitat, describes all the edible species, together with those with which they may be confused. Suggests the best way to cook and preserve different species. Paperback.

ISBN 000721507X 0           no  no          0   no              no          no      Harper Collins  no  0           9999                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    Patrick Harding 
5427    Rest of World Flora > Australasia   A Photographic Guide to Ferns of New Zealand    132pp. Col. photos. Handy pocket guide to help with identification of more than half the islands' native species. Paperback
    7.5         no  no          0.25        no  no      no          no      New Holland no  7.99            0               0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2003    Metcalf, L. 
5428    British Botany > Local Floras > Southern England and the Channel Islands    The Sun Islands: A Natural History of the Isles of Scilly   175pp. 66 col photos. Line drawings. A recent account of the natural history delights of the Scillies, written with charm, verve, and a personal touch. Paperback.

ISBN 1857769694 0           no  no          0       no  no      no      1154    no      Book Guild  no  0       Out of print    0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2005    Patrick Coulcher
5429    Plant Science > General Linnaeus' Philosophia Botanica  402pp. Portrait. Facsimile plates. The first full translation into English of Linnaeus' pioneering work, skilfully rendered by Stephen Freer. Paperback.

ISBN 0198569343 65          no  no          0.9     no  no      no          no      Oxford  no  0       Manufactured on demand - usually dispatched in 1-2 weeks    0               0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2005 (paperback edition)    Carl Linnaeus trans. Stephen Freer
5430    Plant Monographs > Family, Genus and Species    Daphnes: A Practical Guide for Gardeners    232pp. Col. photos. A useful up-to-date treatment of Daphne species and hybrids. The genus is very varied and although many are best known for their noteworthy scent and winter interest, suitable specimens can be found for most situations, seasons, and colour requirements. Hardback; dust-wrapper.

ISBN=10 088192752X  ISBN-13 9780881927528   0           yes no          1       no  no      no          no      Timber Press    no  0       Out of print    0           088192752X|9780881927528|daphnes|practical|guide|gardeners|White|Timber press|book  0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2006    Robin White 
5432    European Flora > Greece, Turkey, Cyprus and the Balkans Wild Flowers of Cyprus  320pp, numerous colour photos. Pocket identification guide to the island's rather special flora, now in a smaller, easy-to-carry format. Paperback

ISBN 9602262664   ISBN  9789602262665   0           no  no          0       no  no      no          no      Efstathiadis Group  no  0           0           Book|Wild|Flowers|Cyprus|Sfikas|9602262664|9789602262665|   0               0       0       0       0       yes No longer in print-Used copies are sometimes availablePlease contact us 99  2006 (Reprint)  George Sfikas
5433    Fauna > Insects and Other Creatures The State of Butterflies in Britain and Ireland 112pp, colour photos, distribution maps. Updated records and trends for the 5 years since the Millennium Atlas of Butterfles was published. Paperback.

ISBN 1874357315 12          no  no          0.71    no              no      1151    no      Pisces Publications no  0           9999                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    R. Fox et al.
5434    Uncategorised   Vietnam: A Natural History  .   0           no  no          0       no  no      no          no          no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       no      99
5435    Plants and People   Deadly Slipper:  A Novel of Death in the Dordogne.  'This literary mystery about a woman's search for her long missing sister takes the reader to the ruggedly beautiful Dordogne region of France - and into the eotic world of orchid hunting, where the discovery of a new species can be deadly...' We recommend as a rattling good read for all lovers of European orchids, French culture and classic crime thrillers.    0           no  no      301pp.
Hardback; with dust-jacket  0       no  no      no          no      Doubleday   no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     55  2005    Wan, M. 
5436    Ecology, Habitat Management and Landscape History > Other Ecology   England's Landscape: The South East 256pp. Numerous colour photos, drawings, maps. Volume 1 in the new series on the English landscape, which seeks to analyse the C21 landscape in terms of its geology, archaeology, environmental value and historical development. Hardback; in dust-jacket.

ISBN 0007155700 0           no  no          0       no  no      no          no      Collins no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       yes OUT OF PRINT    99  2006    Brian Short 
5437    Ecology, Habitat Management and Landscape History > Other Ecology   England's Landscape: The South West 256pp. Numerous colour photographs, maps, plans etc. Volume 3 in the new series on the English landscape, which seeks to analyse the C21 landscape in terms of its geology, archaeology, environmental value and historical development. Hardback; in dust-jacket.

ISBN 0007155727
    0           no  no          1       no  no      no          no      Collins no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       yes OUT OF PRINT    99  2006    Roger Kain
5438    Ecology, Habitat Management and Landscape History > Other Ecology   England's Landscape: The East Midlands  256pp. Many illustrations in colour and black-and-white. Coloured plans and maps. Volume 5 in the new series on the English landscape, which seeks to analyse the C21 landscape in terms of its geology, archaeology, environmental value and historical development. Hardback; in dust-jacket.

ISBN 0007155743
    35          no  no          1   no              no          no      Collins no  0           9999                0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2006    David Stocker
5439    Arboriculture and Trees > Trees Worldwide   Trees of Southern Africa    1,212pp. 314 colour photos. Many text illustrations and distribution maps. The 3rd edition of this substantial and (genuinely) comprehensive guide to South African trees and shrubs, complete with taxonomic keys, carefully defined species accounts, leaf or leaflet drawings for almost all species. Revised and updated by Meg Coates Palgrave. VERY chunky hardback!

ISBN 1868723895 24.75           no  no          3   no              no          no      Struik  no  0           9998            trees|southern Africa| Palgrave|book |1868723895    0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2002 (Reprint)  Keith Coates Palgrave
5440    Plants and People   Nature Cure - paperback A critically acclaimed life-asserting autobiography conceived by Richard Mabey following his emergence from a period of severe depression. He does not spare us the trauma, but proceeds to delight in a reawakening as he exchanges his Chiltern home for Norfolk and re-engages with nature.  0           no  no      232pp. 
Paperback   0.42        no  no      no          no      Pimlico/Random House    no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       yes Out of print    55  2006    Mabey, R.
5441    European Flora > Spain, Portugal, the Canary Islands & the Azores > Flora Iberica   Flora Iberica:  Volume 21.  Smilacaceae-Orchidaceae 263pp. 43 plates of line drawings. 100 colour photographs (exclusively orchids). The orchid volume, with keys to, and descriptions of species and subspecies of Epipactis, Dactylorhiza, Ophrys, etc. Spanish text. Hardback; in dust-jacket.

ISBN 8400083059 39          no  no          1       no  no      no          no      C.S.I.C. Madrid no  0       To order 5-7 days delivery  0               0               0       0       0       0       no      55  2005    S. Castroviejo et al. (eds.)
5442    Arboriculture and Trees > History and Folklore  The Trees That Made Britain 216pp. Many fine colour photos. Published to accompany a BBC series, this lavishly illustrated account of the British tree heritage 'takes us on a journey of discovery to every corner of the nation'. Archie Miles' fine photographs and lively text are introduced by Tony Kirkham and Jon Hammerton of Kew Gardens. Hardback; with dust-jacket.

ISBN 0563493615 0           no  no          1.25        no  no      no          no      BBC Books   no  0           0               0               0       0       0       0       yes     99  2006    Archie Miles
5443    British Botany > Local Floras > Southern England and the Channel Islands    Secret Nature of the Isles of Scilly    224pp. Over 200 colour photographs. A guide to the plant and animal life which make the Scilly Islands special. Arranged largely by area, the reader is introduced to the natural history of both larger and smaller islands, with the emphasis on species of particular interest. Checklists are given at the end of the book. Paperback. 
'''

Comment: Are the numbers that make up the ISBN the only numbers in the description?

Comment: No, unfortunately. This is one of the difficulties. They tend to be small strings (?) such as a year or number of pages which are generally 3 digit long. I will ask permission to upload a sample of the spreadsheet.

Comment: You can also just add sample data to your question with expected output. I'll delete the answer below meanwhile.

Comment: I have added a sample above, column D is where most of the ISBN's have been (wrongly) stored within text. AP is where they should have been stored. In the sample, you can see rows 1-9 where I have manually copied and pasted already.

Comment: Seems to me like you need a regex function to do this for you, to concat all the matched substrings.

Comment: You file will expire in a few days, and people are hesitant to download unknown files even while it exists.  Please edit the question to add a small text table that illustrates the range of conditions.

Comment: Apologies, it was not immediately obvious how to upload a lot of text data, I did look through the help section. When I tried to upload the raw text from the sample it did not work as expected. I have edited the original answer, but any help for how to make it better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this macro.  It seems to work OK on your sample data.

Note that it does not validate that the ISBN is valid, or even in a valid format. The Regular Expression will return any value that consists of nine or more characters where the first character is a digit, and the last character is either a digit or an `X`.

It will also include a beginning tag of `ISBN`, `ISBN-10`, `ISBN 10`, `ISBN-13`, `ISBN 13` if present.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ISBN()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, vSrc As Variant, rRes As Range
    Const srcCol As Long = 4 'D
    Const resCol As Long = 42 'AP
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim I As Long, S As String

Set WS = Worksheets("ISBNSample")
With WS
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, srcCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, srcCol).End(xlUp))
    Set rRes = .Cells(1, resCol)
End With

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "(?:ISBN(?:[\s-]1[03])?)?:?\s*\b(\d[\d\s-]{8,}[\dx])\b"
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        S = vSrc(I, 1)
        vSrc(I, 1) = ""
        If .test(S) = True Then
            Set MC = .Execute(S)
                For Each M In MC
                    vSrc(I, 1) = vSrc(I, 1) & vbLf & M
                Next M
                vSrc(I, 1) = Mid(vSrc(I, 1), 2)
        End If
    Next I
End With

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vSrc, 1), 1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    With .EntireColumn
        .Clear
        .ColumnWidth = 255
    End With

    .Value = vSrc
    .WrapText = True
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm, I changed the code to look in different columns (the column number threw me the first time) This has saved my client a considerable amount of effort. We are based in the UK. Name a type of charity and I will make a donation, with thanks. Or, if there is another way to thank you please let me know. Also, it has set me on a route to study Macros. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  Glad to help.  For me, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information. 
.  WRT charities, we usually give locally, where we have direct knowledge of how the funds are spent, and that would be OK. Internationally, we have donated to Save the Children (which actually started in the UK, I believe).